# Numpy cumulative distribution function (CDF)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, statistics

I have an array of values and have created a histogram of the data using numpy.histogram, as follows:

```
histo = numpy.histogram(arr, nbins)
```

where nbins is the number of bins derived from the range of the data (max-min) divided by a desired bin width.

From the output I create a cumulative distribution function using:

```
cdf = np.cumsum(histo[0])
normCdf = cdf/np.amax(cdf)
```

However, I need an array of normCdf values that corresponds with the values in the original array (arr). For example, if a value in the original array arr is near the minimum value of arr then its corresponding normCdf value will be high (i.e 0.95). (In this example, as I am working with radar data my data is in decibels and is negative. Therefore the lowest value is where the CDF reaches its maximum.)

Im struggling, conceptually, how I achieve an array whereby each value in the array has its corresponding value under the CDF (normCdf value). Any help would be appreciated. The histogram with the cdf is below.

[image]

Comment: A couple of things to note here: `np.histogram` has a `density` keyword, which you might want to use for the empirical cumulative density. The red curve in your plot is not a `cdf`, but probably a 1-`cdf`. Using `cumsum` is the right approach, but you then get a function that maps the position of each bin to the cumulative density.

Comment: I looked at the density option but it returns a pdf not a cdf, where the integral of the area under the curve is 1, not the cumulated total. Im happy that I have the correct values I need but I want to index them using the original array

Comment: The easiest way is probably using the empirical cumulative density function implementation from statsmodels: http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/0.6.0/generated/statsmodels.distributions.empirical_distribution.ECDF.html

Comment: Solved it be iterating through the values in the original array and calculating  (originalArray - minOfOriginalArray)/binwidth and using the result to index the CDF array

Comment: @NathanThomas Would you mind elaborating on your solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but may still be of help to someone.

Consider the OP's last sentence:

> Im struggling, conceptually, how I achieve an array whereby each value in the array has its corresponding value under the CDF (normCdf value).

If I understand correctly, what the OP is asking for, actually boils down to the (normalized) *ordinal rank* of the array elements.

The ordinal rank of an array element `i` basically indicates how many elements in the array have a value smaller than that of element `i`. This is equivalent to the discrete cumulative density.

Ordinal ranking is related to sorting by the following equality (where `u` is an unsorted list):

```py
u == [sorted(u)[i] for i in ordinal_rank(u)]
```

Based on the [implementation of scipy.stats.rankdata](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.7.1/scipy/stats/stats.py#L8631-L8737), the ordinal rank can be computed as follows:

```py
def ordinal_rank(data):
    rank = numpy.empty(data.size)
    rank[numpy.argsort(data)] = numpy.arange(data.size)
    return rank
```

So, to answer the OP's question:

The normalized (empirical) cumulative density corresponding to the values in the OP's `arr` can then be computed as follows:

```py
normalized_cdf = ordinal_rank(arr) / len(arr)
```

And the result can be displayed using:

```py
pyplot.plot(arr, normalized_cdf, marker='.', linestyle='')
```

Note, that, if you only need the plot, there is an easier way:

```py
n = len(arr)
pyplot.plot(numpy.sort(arr), numpy.arange(n) / n)
```

And, finally, we can verify this by plotting the cumulative normalized histogram as follows (using an arbitrary number of bins):

```py
pyplot.hist(arr, bins=100, cumulative=True, density=True)
```

Here's an example comparing the three approaches, using 30 bins for the cumulative histogram:

[image: empirical cumulative density]